# Using nested for loop to add 2 Linked Lists with java.util.ListIterator;

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to iterate through two Linked lists using a for loop and the listIterator method.

I am trying to accomplish the method below which adds two polynomials using a linked list

`public Polynomial add(Polynomial p)`

POSTCONDITION: this object and p are not changed
return a polynomial that is the sum of p and this polynomial

Here is my method

```
public Polynomial add( Polynomial p )
{
    // use the copy constructor
    Polynomial answer = new Polynomial( this );
    // answer.termList.addAll(p.termList);
    // use addAll()
    //answer=this.termList.addAll(p.termList);
    //ListIterator<Term> itr = answer.termList.listIterator();
    //ListIterator<Term> itr = answer.termList.listIterator();
    //ListIterator<Term> itr2 = p.termList.listIterator();
    for ( ListIterator<Term> itr = answer.termList.listIterator(); itr.hasNext(); )
    {
        Term term = itr.next();

        for ( ListIterator<Term> itr2 = p.termList.listIterator(); itr2.hasNext(); )
        {
            Term term2 = itr2.next();
            if ( term.exponent == term2.exponent )
            {
                answer.itr.coefficient = answer.itr.coefficient + p.itr2.coefficient;
            }
        }
        /**while ( itr.hasNext() )
         {
         Term term = itr.next();
         }**/
        return answer;

    }
}
```

This line  `for (ListIterator<Term> itr=answer.termList.listIterator();itr.hasNext();)` and `for(ListIterator<Term> itr2 = p.termList.listIterator(); itr2.hasNext();)` have errors.

I keep getting an error that says itr and itr2 cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Here is part of the code that defines Polynomial there are a lot of methods which I didn't include since they are too long.

```
public class Polynomial implements Cloneable
{
    // this is a nested static class, it defines a type
    // all the instance varaibles can be access directly inside Polynomial
    // class even though they have

    // private modifier
    private static class Term
    {
        private int exponent;
        private double coefficient;

        public Term( int exp, double coeff )
        {
            coefficient = coeff;
            exponent = exp;
        }
    }

    // instance variables of Polynomial
    // first is the term of the Polynomial with the highest degree
    private LinkedList<Term> termList;

    /**
     * Postcondition:  Creates a polynomial which is 0.
     **/
    public Polynomial()
    {
        termList = new LinkedList<Term>();
        termList.add( new Term( 0, 0 ) );
    }

    /**
     * Postcondition:  Creates a polynomial which has a single term
     * a0*x^0
     *
     * @param a0 The value to be set as the coefficient of the
     *           constant (x^0) t                      erm.
     **/
    public Polynomial( double a0 )
    {
        termList = new LinkedList<Term>();
        termList.add( new Term( 0, a0 ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that defines `Polynomial`

Comment: Please indicate which line(s) has the errors

Comment: come-on, please make some effort to format your code

Comment: the termList member is declared private, isn’t this an issue in the add method? And please remove all code that has been commented out.

Comment: @ScaryWombat 
what do you need?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson actually let me look at that, I changed it to public and it did not solve the error

Comment: Polynomial isn’t a static class as far as I can see

Comment: yea I was thinking of the class Term

Comment: Are the terms in the list sorted by exponent?

Comment: @MauricePerry no :/ I need to figure out how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the faulty line

```
answer.itr.coefficient= answer.itr.coefficient + p.itr2.coefficient;
```

itr and itr2 are iterator objects and not members of `Polynomial`, I guess what you meant was

```
term.coefficient += term2.coefficient;
```

---

**Update**

For completeness here is my full version of the `add` method

```
public Polynomial add(Polynomial p) {
    Polynomial answer = new Polynomial(this);
    for (ListIterator<Term> itr = answer.termList.listIterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        Term term = itr.next();

        for (ListIterator<Term> itr2 = p.termList.listIterator(); itr2.hasNext();) {
            Term term2 = itr2.next();
            if (term.exponent == term2.exponent) {
                term.coefficient += term2.coefficient;
            } else {
                answer.termList.add(new Term(term2.exponent, term2.coefficient));
            }
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: thanks! that solved that error!
now its giving me another error
method must return type Polynomial but I thought I declared answer as  a Polynomial

Comment: @Preston I don't get that error so you must have done something else with the code.

Comment: ok I fixed that.. Now I added an else statement after the if statement 
`else
              answer.termList.add(new Term(term2.exponent,term2.coefficient));//exp,coeff*/`
 
to add a node if term2 has an exponent that term1 does not have but I can't update the linked list while its iterating apparently I'm trying to figure out how to get around this

Comment: @Preston add new objects to a local ArrayList or similar and then add the content to termList after the iterator loops

Comment: I'm just learning LinkedLists in class and I'm not familar with ArrayList would you mind showing me how to do that?

Comment: @Preston, actually you don't need an ArrayList it should work fine just to add the term, `else {
                   answer.termList.add(term2);
               }` since you then update the termList object and not the iterator.

Comment: It will compile okay but when I run it it gives me a ConcurrentModificationException error when I do that

Comment: @Preston, that is a completely different error due to threading, you need to create a new question for that. I have only the code you posted and a simple `main()` method to test `add()` and I do not have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The loops don't have to be nested.

This solution will keep the terms sorted by descending order of the exponent:

```
public class Polynomial {
    private List<Term> termList = new LinkedList<Term>();

    private static class Term {
        private int exponent;
        private double coefficient;

        private Term(int exponent, double coefficient) {
            this.exponent = exponent;
            this.coefficient = coefficient;
        }
    }

    public Polynomial() {
    }

    public Polynomial(int exponent, double coeff) {
        if (coeff != 0) {
            termList.add(new Term(exponent, coeff));
        }
    }

    public Polynomial add(Polynomial other) {
        Polynomial answer = new Polynomial();
        Iterator<Term> itr = termList.iterator();
        Iterator<Term> itr2 = other.termList.iterator();
        Term t = itr.hasNext() ? itr.next() : null;
        Term t2 = itr2.hasNext() ? itr2.next() : null;
        while (true) {
            if (t == null) {
                if (t2 == null) {
                    break;
                }
                answer.termList.add(new Term(t2.exponent, t2.coefficient));
                t2 = itr2.hasNext() ? itr2.next() : null;
            } else if (t2 == null) {
                answer.termList.add(new Term(t.exponent, t.coefficient));
                t = itr.hasNext() ? itr.next() : null;
            } else if (t2.exponent > t.exponent) {
                answer.termList.add(new Term(t2.exponent, t2.coefficient));
                t2 = itr2.hasNext() ? itr2.next() : null;
            } else if (t2.exponent < t.exponent) {
                answer.termList.add(new Term(t.exponent, t.coefficient));
                t = itr.hasNext() ? itr.next() : null;
            } else {
                answer.termList.add(
                        new Term(t.exponent, t.coefficient + t2.coefficient));
                t = itr.hasNext() ? itr.next() : null;
                t2 = itr2.hasNext() ? itr2.next() : null;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I tried to use your solution in main it gave me this
` Polynomial p4 = p2.add(p3);`

this below is the output
`p2 = new Polynomial(): p2 = 3.0x^3 + -4.0x^4 `

`p3 = new Polynomial(): p3 = -4.0x^4 + -4.0x^2 `

`p4 = -4.0x^4 + 3.0x^3 + -4.0x^4 + -4.0x^2 +`

Comment: @Preston the terms of the input polynomials must be sorted (and kept that way)